# Remove border and shadow from DocumentViewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, documentviewer

Good evening. I have been chasing an issue with DocumentViewer and don't know how to address it.

When you display a document in a DocumentViewer control, it displays a border and a shadow around the document and I do not know how to get rid of it.

I have written a control template, which I would have expected to have addressed the issue and it does not. Here it is:

```
  <Style x:Key="MyDocStyle" TargetType="DocumentViewer">
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="DocumentViewer">
              <Border BorderThickness="5" >
              <Grid>
                 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                               Background="Transparent"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" >
                 </ScrollViewer>
              </Grid>
              </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

What else am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much. I'm not sure how I missed that. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I want to point out, though, that you've posted this as an answer to your own question, rather than any kind of reply (I just happened to look back and see it). Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If someone answers your question correctly here, the usual action is to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you don't need to alter the ControlTemplate at all. May I point out [`DocumentViewer.ShowPageBorders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.documentviewer.showpageborders):

> Indicates whether drop-shadow page borders are displayed

Usage:

```
<DocumentViewer ShowPageBorders="False"/>
```